# How to Override a Pluggable Function

Tags: plugins

How can I override a function in pluggable.php?

I have tried making my own plugin -- got the fatal error on function already defined.

I tried functions.php in my theme -- got the white screen.

Is it possible to override a pluggable.php function without touching the source code file itself?

Thanks.

**Here is the function I wish to override (located in ../wp-includes/pluggable.php):**

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) :
/**
 * Notify the blog admin of a new user, normally via email.
 *
 * @since 2.0
 *
 * @param int $user_id User ID
 * @param string $plaintext_pass Optional. The user's plaintext password
 */
function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plaintext_pass = '') {
...
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which function are you trying to override? And can you provide the code (or a snippet) so we can see in what scope you are defining your function?

Comment: @William -- I revised my question to include the function() I am trying to override.

Comment: Try putting the code in your theme functions.php and setting `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config.php` file so you can see what errors are being thrown. EDIT: by "the code" I mean your function override.

Comment: Ok, will do @William. I got the white screen first time through...this time I will use debug. My guess is it will yell at me for a duplicate fucntion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap it in a `function_exists` check:

```
if( ! function_exists('some_pluggable_function') ) {
    function some_pluggable_function()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Milo but that merely prevents the fatal error. It does not result in my function superseding the pluggable.php call hence my function ends up not running -- the pluggable.php function does.

Comment: Here's the answer:

See http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/customizing-new-user-email-pluggable-function/

It does not make sense that you need to wrap *your* overriding function with the function_exists() even though it is wrapped in pluggable.php, but you do!

That's the trick. SO you are right @Milo.

Comment: the reason it needs to be wrapped in `function_exists` is because within the context of a plugin activation, the function *does* already exist. This is due to the way WordPress activates plugins in a sandbox, which is necessary to enable it to recover from fatal errors in the activated plugin. Technically, once the plugin is activated the `function_exists` check would not be necessary, but you'd never be able to activate that plugin via conventional means without it.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to override functions in `pluggable.php` is to redefine the same function in a plugin.  Your plugin's function will override the one in `pluggable.php` since the WP one is wrapped in a call to `function_exists()`.

But make sure you're only doing this *once*.  From [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions):

> **Note:** A function can only be reassigned this way once, so you can’t install two plugins that plug the same function for different reasons. For safety, it is best to always wrap your functions with `if ( !function_exists() )`, otherwise you will produce fatal errors on plugin activation.

From what you describe happening, it sounds like more than one plugin is trying to override the same function.

Comment: Thanks @EAMann but "I have tried making my own plugin -- got the fatal error on function already defined."

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. Wish I found this answer sooner. Now it makes sense why MY plugin can't override the function that another plugin is overriding. :(