# How to Override A Function in ms-functions.php

Tags: pluggable

I want to execute my own welcome new user email notification instead of `function welcome_user_msg_filter(){}` located in ms-functions.php

I recently [learned how to override functions in pluggable.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56571/how-to-override-a-pluggable-function), but the function I am referencing does not have its own `if ( ! function_exists( 'welcome_user_msg_filter' ) ) {}`.

Has anyone ever overridden a function that lives in `ms-functions.php`?

If so, how do you go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Functions, which aren't wrapped inside `functions_exists()` calls, are not meant to be pluggable. If you're searching for extensions, then use filters or hooks - in case there're some.

As you can read in the phpDocBlock:

> Ensure that the welcome message is not empty. Currently unused.

So this filter won't work.

---

I'm no MU expert, but maybe you can make use of the following filter:

```
apply_filters( 'wpmu_signup_blog_notification_email',
    __( "To activate your blog, please click the following link:\n\n%s\n\nAfter you activate, you will receive *another email* with your login.\n\nAfter you activate, you can visit your site here:\n\n%s" ),
    $domain, $path, $title, $user, $user_email, $key, $meta
)
```

You'd call it like this:

```
function wpse56797_signup_blog_notification_email( $message, $domain, $path, $title, $user, $user_email, $key, $meta )
{
    $message = 'Your custom notification';
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_blog_notification_email', 'wpse56797_signup_blog_notification_email', 10, 8 );
```

Comment: Ok, thanks @kaiser. Do I need to code both your apply_filters() and your function/add_filter() from your example? AND do I make them a custom plugin? Also, I am looking to intercept `function welcome_user_msg_filter()` so I assume where you have `wpse56797_signup_blog_notification_email` mine would be `welcome_user_msg_filter`

Comment: Pleas read my answer - in detail the quote I copied from the phpDocBlock - again. Then go and read through other questions inside the [tag:apply_filters] to see the difference between "add" and "apply". Then take a look at the ms-functions.php file again and see where the `apply_filters` comes from.

Comment: Ok, thanks @kaiser. I did read your answer and I apologize as i am just a stupid person. I am not seeing how your example gets me to overriding `function welcome_user_msg_filter(){}` located ms-functions.php. I'll plug along though. Appreciate your time.

Comment: The phpDocBlock (in Core code above the function you're referring too), states _"Ensure that the welcome message is not empty. Currently unused."_ . And that means, that the function isn't in use and therefore you can't use it as it won't influence anything. It's like standing in a crowd of people, shouting "PETER", when there's no one named "Peter" and therefore no one will respond.

Comment: I am too thick on this @kaiser. I don't know how to "ensure that the welcome message is not empty". And does "currently unused" mean that the function is not in use? Because I can tell you that on my install v3.3.2 whenever I add a new user, an email is generated coming from what is inside `function welcome_user_msg_filter(){}`. All I want to do is intercept that function and run my own.

Comment: _"Ensure that the welcome message is not empty."_ is the _description_ of the function. _"Currently unused."_ means that it's not in use.

Comment: @frank13 Btw: Have you already tried the other filter?