# Customized wp_new_user_notification

Tags: functions, pluggable

Customized wp_new_user_notification

I'm kind of inexperienced with it comes to editing Wordpress functions, yet i'm currently trying to customize [`wp_new_user_notification`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1188) in order to personalize the email that administrators and users receive once they register. I'm aware there's some plugins that allow this kind of customization, but I would rather spend some more time on a problem and try to learn/understand it, rather than just install a plugin. 
Hence, I've placed this function in my `functions.php`, and I believe I'm supposed to add one or more filters, such as:

```
add_filter('myfunction', 'wp_new_user_notification', ?, ?)
```

or maybe not. I've read and attempted to follow several tips/tutorials/questions ([such as](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56571/how-to-override-a-pluggable-function) for example), but no matter what I do, I keep receiving emails with standard text/contents (as if my functions is not being considered by Wordpress).

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only override pluggable functions in a plugin, not via `functions.php`. The function is already defined when `functions.php` is loaded, which is why your overriding function is skipped. Move the code to [your own plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

### When do Plugins load?

Plugins are loaded right before the `plugins_loaded` hook. MU-Plugins (this is what every pluggable imho should be), are loaded even earlier, before the `muplugins_loaded`-hook. (Both are the first hooks for plugins and run *much* earlier than every hook accessible for themes).

### What exactly are Pluggables?

"Pluggables" are called like this, because they can get "plugged out" in core and replaced. This happens, because they are wrapped in a `if ( ! function_exists( 'some_pluggable_fn' ) ) {` calls.

You can find the im `pluggable.php` in core or sometimes in a Themes `functions.php` file - take TwentyTen/*Eleven as example.

```
<?php
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/** Plugin Name: (pluggable) Replace New User Notification function */

function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
    // define the functionality of your new function.
}
```